On Connecting Bricks.SE and LEGO User Groups
One of the reasons that I am involved with Bricks.SE is because I don't have (that I know of) any LEGO community near where I live (Southern Oregon).  However, I used to live in the SF Bay area, and was part of BayLUG, and that got me thinking:
How can we leverage the power of LUGs to grow Bricks.SE, and how can we leverage the power of Bricks.SE to build LUGs?
I don't have any particular thoughts on this issue, other than desired results:  I'd like to see Bricks.SE become a larger community, and see more LUGs around the country (especially in my area).

One possible solution is to expand our outreach to the LUGs.  I assume that many members here are already part of a local LUG, and perhaps we could get them some SE swag to hand out at the LUG meetings.
And though (at the risk of sounding like a dating site) a "Meet people in your area" thread isn't suitable for the format of SE, we could seed some questions about locating LUGs, and meeting other LEGO fans in your area (for example, referring to forums that have those kind of threads).
Any other ideas to help establish a strong partnership here?

I fully endorse asking a Community-Wiki question about the current LUGs - it would need to be a Wiki though so that people are happy to contribute and maintain "one definitive answer" rather than have lots of individual ones. We'd need to work to ensure that it wasn't just a direct repeat of LUGNET's US and Global lists though.

On Mi Yodeya (Judaism.SE), there is a meta topic for finding places where lots of people live, so that an IRL get-together might be possible. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/where-do-you-live

One other possible solution is to recognize Bricks.se as a valid LEGO community - a decentralized LUG, if you will. Some other online communities (I'm thinking eurobricks) have done it that way.
With the revamping of the LEGO ambassador program as the LEGO Ambassador Network, maybe it would be interesting to try to push one key member of bricks.se as ambassador.

I'm not knocking Bricks.SE as a valid community.  After all, this is my goto community for LEGO-related matters now.  The issue, on my mind, is that LUGs provide some benefits that a decentralized community can never provide.  At the very least, you have LUGBulk, but since LEGO is inherently a physical medium, it's nice to have other people in close proximity that you can turn to.  That allows you to organize displays, work with after-school programs, and generally spread LEGO into the local community.  Which is just something that isn't very easy to coordinate from Bricks.SE.
